# AudioUnit Render callback issue (callback not invoked)

Tags: ios, callback, core-audio, audiounit

I have a simple requirement at this point, an iOS app that reads from an audio file and outputs to a speaker using AudioUnits. The reason behind not using high-level APIs is, at some point, I need to process the samples coming out of the audio file and eventually send it across network.

I have a code that works, reads the audio file and plays back to the speaker. The only issue here is, the render callback isn't working. The callback never gets called, neither do I receive any error while registering the same. Help is much appreciated (I am a beginner on Core Audio and this is my first question on stackoverflow, so please pardon any basic mistakes/overlooks). The piece of code I use for initializing the graph is attached.

```
void createMyAUGraph (MyAUGraphPlayerST *player) {
    // Create a new AUGraph

    CheckError(NewAUGraph(&player->graph), "New AUGraph failed");

    // Generate description for output

    AudioComponentDescription outputcd = {0};
    outputcd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    outputcd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    outputcd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    outputcd.componentFlags = 0;
    outputcd.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    // Add new node

    AUNode outputNode;
    CheckError(AUGraphAddNode(player->graph, &outputcd, &outputNode), "Add output node failed");

    // Node for file player

    AudioComponentDescription fileplayercd = {0};
    fileplayercd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;
    fileplayercd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer;
    fileplayercd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    // Add new node

    AUNode fileNode;
    CheckError(AUGraphAddNode(player->graph, &fileplayercd, &fileNode), "Add file node failed");

    // Open graph

    CheckError(AUGraphOpen(player->graph), "Graph open failed");

    // Retrive AudioUnit

    CheckError(AUGraphNodeInfo(player->graph, outputNode, NULL, &player->outputAU), "file unit retrive failed");
    CheckError(AUGraphNodeInfo(player->graph, fileNode, NULL, &player->fileAU), "file unit retrive failed");

    // connect nodes

    CheckError(AUGraphConnectNodeInput(player->graph, fileNode, 0, outputNode, 0), "failed to connect nodes");

    // some other setup

    UInt32 flag = 1;
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(player->outputAU,
                                      kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                                      kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                      0,
                                      &flag,
                                      sizeof (flag)), "Set io property failed");

    // Register render callback

    AURenderCallbackStruct output_cb;
    output_cb.inputProc = recording_cb;
    output_cb.inputProcRefCon = player;
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(player->outputAU, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &output_cb, sizeof (output_cb)), "callback register failed");

    // initialize graph

    CheckError(AUGraphInitialize(player->graph), "graph initialization failed");
}
```

Comment: Where is the render callback?

Comment: What is your audio session category?

Comment: Hi Matt, I am trying to use AudioUnits without the AudioSession. My understanding, from some of the docs I went thru was, they can be used independently. The reading and playback of audio file is working as expected, I am just not able to get to the samples. Do I need to setup the AudioSession for the callback to work? The render callback is not getting invoked, hence I did not include the code piece here.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You told the graph to connect your RemoteIO's input to the file player node, not to your render callback.  Then you initialized the graph, which overrode your render property.</s>

<s>If you want to pull samples from a file to process, your processing routine or render callback will have to do so, not the connection from the player output to the RemoteIO input.  So don't let the graph make that connection.</s>

Updated answer:

On any recent iOS version, you need to first use the Audio Session API to request microphone privacy permission before starting the Audio Units, otherwise you will only get silence from the microphone.

To use Audio Units to record and play thru as well as record, try putting callbacks on both the output and input of RemoteIO, then pass the sample data between the two callbacks using a circular buffer.  Inside one or both of the callbacks, you can record or modify the samples as needed.  Make sure to heed real-time restrictions inside the audio context (no locks or memory management, etc.)

Comment: Are you sure about the overriding of render property? Most of the examples I referred to, including the iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest from Apple, seem to connect nodes, set the  render callbacks and then initialize the graph. A comment in the code (iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest app) reads "// now that we've set everything up we can initialize the graph, this will also validate the connections" while initializing the graph. I need to play the packets, from the audio file, on the device speaker, hence the connection from file to RemoteIO.

Comment: But at the same time, I also want access to the packets, via render callback to process and send it over the net. That part is not working and am not able to grasp my head around where to set the callback for it to work as expected.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on this, and I'm not sure what @hotpaw2 is saying here.